# Minesweeper miscalculation

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, minesweeper

I'm trying to implement Minesweeper in Python, using Tkinter to create the GUI. I'm having an issue with the functionality to count the mines adjacent to a square.

Here is the code where I set up the board as a list of lists. I assign the value `9` to indicate a mine.

```
from random import randint

# example values for testing
mines = 10
board = (10, 10)

mine_matrix = []
for line_number in range(board[1]):
        new_mine_line = []
        for column_number in range(board[0]):
            new_mine_line.append(0)
        mine_matrix.append(new_mine_line)

for mine in range(mines_amount):
    while True:
        mine_x = randint(0, board[1]-1)
        mine_y = randint(0, board[0]-1)
        if mine_matrix[mine_x][mine_y] < 8:
            mine_matrix[mine_x][mine_y] = 9
            break
```

Then I use this code to account for the number of adjacent mines. It should iterate over the field to look for the `9` values; when one is found, it should access the adjacent values (by iterating over values in `control` and adding them to the row and column indices) and add `1` to each.

```
control = -1, 0, 1
for line in range(board[1]):
    for column in range(board[0]):
        if mine_matrix[line][column] > 8:
            for line_control in control:
                for column_control in control:
                    try:
                        if (line == 0 or column == 0) and (line_control == -1 or column_control == -1): continue
                        mine_matrix[line+line_control][column+column_control] += 1
                    except: continue
```

I expect the `if... continue` code and the `try`/`except` logic to avoid problematic values (e.g. trying to subtract from the column index when looking at the left edge).

However, when I try running the code, some of the buttons have the wrong number on them.
[image]

For example, looking specifically at this part:

[image]

The middle square shows a 1, but there are two adjacent mines (marked in red).

What is wrong, and how do I fix the problem?

Comment: Your program is failing due to an IndexError, but that bare `except:` is throwing away the error details so you can't tell what went wrong.  The first thing you need to do is get rid of that `try`, so you can actually see what is happening.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. We want questions to be direct and to the point; do not talk about yourself. We can (and will) fix your writing (that is no problem) but it is better if there is less that has to be removed. Please see how I edited the question, in order to understand proper style. Please also keep in mind that we cannot rely on external links. If there is too much code to put in the question, then it is too much code for us to consider. The code that you have already shown us here seems like the right amount already.

Comment: (I just added a few lines at the top to make a proper [mre] - hope you don't mind.)

Comment: Anyway, this is a simple logical error. The `if` condition will be met, for example, in cases where `line` is equal to `0` and `column_control` is equal to `-1`, even though there is nothing wrong with checking "above" a mine that is "on the left edge" (except in the top-left corner). Instead, try separately calculating the `line+line_control` and `column+column_control` values first, and separately check whether those sums are good index values.

Comment: (Generally, we do not want to keep questions like this, because they cannot be very useful to others; mistakes that people make in *understanding* can be explained and taught about, but mistakes in *logic* just require thinking more carefully. Other people are not likely to make the same mistake, and if they do make that mistake, they cannot easily use a search engine to find a question about it.)

Comment: @jasonharper I initially agreed with you on instinct, but that is wrong here - the exception logic is being specifically used to avoid `IndexError`. The code *should* mention that name explicitly, but the problem is not being caused by a different kind of exception being caught unintentionally - as the goal is to do nothing in the cases where the computed indices are out of bounds. The problem is that the `if` statement also incorrectly catches some cases where the indices are *in* bounds.

Comment: (The `try`/`except` logic can't handle the top and left edges of the board properly because a `-1` index for a list is valid in Python and will not cause `IndexError`. However, since `if` logic is necessary to handle these cases anyway, it would be better to use that logic for all of the board edges.)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel agree with your comments.  Another option would be to use a mine matrix that is one larger, so the checked values always have valid indices.  Would need some explaining comments in the code why this hack works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that both `line+line_control` and `column+column_control` are within valid range, then you don't need the `try/except` actually:

```py
control = (-1, 0, 1)
for line in range(board[1]):
    for column in range(board[0]):
        if mine_matrix[line][column] > 8:
            for line_control in control:
                for column_control in control:
                    if not (line_control == column_control == 0):
                        r, c = line+line_control, column+column_control
                        # make sure both r and c are within valid range
                        if (0 <= r < board[1]) and (0 <= c < board[0]):
                            mine_matrix[r][c] += 1
```